# UIActionSheet _button valueforKey Crash in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactionsheet

In `iOS 8` , following codes crash that add image to `UIActionSheet's` `_button` `valueForKey.`

```
UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Choose Action!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Start Auto Scroll", nil];

[[[action valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"autoScroll.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[action showInView:self.view];
```

Crash Log is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIActionSheet 0x7ff6d8c61030> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _buttons.'
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: any thing you got ??

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing was never legal. You cannot modify an action sheet's interface directly. If your code was ever getting past the App Store Guardians, that was just an oversight.

Use a custom presentation transition animation to make a view controller view that looks like an action sheet (or, indeed, one that doesn't look like an action sheet). Making a presented view controller view that partially covers the screen is easy and legal in iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: In iOS 7 , above code is fine. Only happening in iOS8.

Comment: Listen to what I'm telling you. It isn't fine. iOS 8 has (correctly) closed the loophole that allowed you do something you should not have been doing. There is an easy and correct way to do this. I've told you what it is. Accept that fact and move on.

Comment: I've even written an article describing how to do this, along with downloadable code that has been revised for iOS 8: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html